# jquery API Data not updating correctly - 1 number to low

Tags: jquery, html, json, api

I'm doing an API call to buy an item, which updates the JSON with +1. If I go to the API URL directly it shows the correct number. However the jquery is not updating properly. It seems that when I click the button it is 1 integer to low. For example I start on 10 and I click twice it's on 11. Yet the actual URL returns 12.

```
$('.buy-pack-btn').click(function(){
        var productName = $(this).attr('data-value');
        var url = "/api/cart/addtocart.json?product=" + productName;
        $.post(url);
        itemsInCart();
        console.log(url);
    });

function itemsInCart() {
    $.get( "/api/cart/cartquantity.json", function(data){
        console.log("Quanitity: " + data);
        if (data > 0) {
            var itemsCart = '<div class="items-in-cart animated bounceIn">';
            itemsCart += data + '</div>';
            console.log(itemsCart);
            console.log("Quanitity: " + data);
            $('.cart-icon').html(itemsCart);
        }
    });
}
```

Do I need to add a delay or something? Thing is I want to update the HTML in realtime. So the second a person clicks on + or X or - on an item I need to value to change on the cart.

Comment: `$.post(url, itemsInCart);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Still not updating correctly tho.

Comment: Your get request in itemsInCart might be processed prior to you post request.

Comment: How can I change this order or add a delay?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding a delay this way.

```
function itemsInCart() {
    setTimeout(function(){
          $.get( "https://service-experience.nl/api/cart/cartquantity.json", function(data){
            console.log("Quanitity: " + data);
            if (data > 0) {
                var itemsCart = '<div class="items-in-cart animated bounceIn">';
                itemsCart += data + '</div>';
                console.log(itemsCart);
                console.log("Quanitity: " + data);
                $('.cart-icon').html(itemsCart);
            }
        });
    }, 100);

}
```